# jQuery selector returns duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I'm trying to select with jQuery all the rows from a table except the first one (column titles) and for that I have this selector:

```
$("#tableID tr:not(:first)")
```

Having three rows, one for column titles, and two for content, the selector returns 4, but if I do:

```
$("#tableID tr")
```

It returns the three rows just fine. Am I missing something in the selector?

I made a screenshot if it helps:

[image]

The code that gives me the problem is this (it is stupidly simple, I don't understand why it doesn't work)

```
    function addTableColumn() {
        var uls = $('#debate ul').length;
        $('#debate tr:first ').append("<th id='foo'>foo title</th>");    
        $("#debate tr:not(#debate tr:first)").append("<td><ul id='sortable" + (uls+1) + "' class='connectedSortable'></ul></td>").hide().fadeIn("slow");
        alert("I'm seeing " + $('#debate tr:not(:first)').length + " rows (without first row), type: " + $('#debate tr:not(:first)')[0] + " but the row count returns (including titles) " + $('#debate tr').length);
        makeSortable();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a title row, I would recommend changing your markup to something like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then, in your CSS/jQuery, only select the `<tr>`s in `<tbody>`, it's also more semantic this way.

Comment: After separating the titles from the tbody and making the selector $('#tableID tbody tr'), the row count was fine. Thanks, this was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
$('#tableID tr:gt(0)')
```

but what you have should work!

Answer (score -1):

`$("#tableID tr:not(:first)")` works just fine .

Comment: How's that different from OP's?

Comment: Well i took time to verifiy that this code works.. and the question was answred in that time. and yes it's the same code :)

Comment: Apparently it doesn't for the OP so please don't post useless answers, instead, use comments.

Comment: this is the second time i get downvotes , and people just say use comments , how can you comment the original post ? And i understand that people must downvote when the reponse is useless , but i don't think that this reponse was useless .. The  OP should have known by this reponse that  he missed soemthing to tell us in the markup..

Comment: i think so too. if the answer is correct, you should not downvote it. i would also think, that the selector is correct, but the page has some markup-issues (like unclosed elements).